# How to check if all the fields of a form are filled?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, addeventlistener

I want to check if all my inputs are filled to activate a submit button, but with my code it checks only one input.

My HTML (with TWIG) :

```html
<div class="content-wrapper  content-wrapper--close">
    <form class="form form--width">
        <fieldset class="form__fieldset input">
            <input class="input__field" id="name" name="name"/>
            <label class="input__label" for="name">Nom et prénom</label>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="form__fieldset input">
            <input class="input__field" id="structure" name="structure"/>
            <label class="input__label" for="structure">Structure</label>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="form__fieldset input">
            <input class="input__field" id="email" name="email"/>
            <label class="input__label" for="email">Adresse email</label>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset class="form__fieldset input">
            <textarea class="input__field input__field--textarea" name="message" id="message" rows="10">
            </textarea>
            <label class="input__label" for="message">Message</label>
        </fieldset>   

        <fieldset class="form__fieldset">
            <div class="cta is-disabled">
                <input type="submit" class="cta__link button" value="Envoyer">
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

My javascript:

```js
/**
 * Add event listener on input.
 *
 * @param form
*/
addListener(form) {
    const inputs = form.querySelectorAll('.input__field');

    [...inputs].map( input => {
        input.addEventListener('focus', (event) => {
            event.target.classList.add('is-fill');
        });

        input.addEventListener('blur', (event) => {
            if (event.target.value === '') {
                event.target.classList.remove('is-fill');
            }
        });
    });
}

// // If all fields are filled, remove class 'is-disabled'

handleInputs(items) {
    const inputs = items.querySelectorAll('.input__field');
    const submitButton = document.querySelector('.form .cta');

    [...inputs].map( input => {
        input.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
            if(e.target.value !== '') {
                submitButton.classList.remove('is-disabled');
            } else {
                if(!submitButton.classList.contains('is-disabled')) {
                    submitButton.classList.add('is-disabled');
                }
            }
        });
    });
}
```

For now it only works with only one input and I don't know how to do to check all the input. If somebody can help me, I don't find any answer.
Thanks

Comment: do you realize the browser does this by default with `required` attributes.

Comment: For your solution, you would need to loop over every input. Also map() is not the best thing to use since you are not mapping data to a new array, you should be using a forEach loop.

Comment: @epascarello Make this an answer.  Usually the simplest and most direct answer is the best one.

Comment: @epascarello thanks for your answer but what I want is to add an `is-disabled` class on my `input [submit]`, required just prevent the form from being sent until all the fields are filled.

Comment: @ArcanumLibella Added answer showing you how you can apply a style to the button when the inputs are all not filled in correctly.

Answer (score 2):

With HTML5 you can style the form button when the form is not invalid. Simple CSS rule and it will apply the styles. It also by default prevents the form from submitting.

The button will remain red until the form is filled in with a valid name, email, and date. I also added a rule that alters the current element being edited which your code is also doing.

```css
input {
  margin: .5rem;
}

input:focus {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px #0ff;
}

form:invalid input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>User:</legend>
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" required><br> 
    <label for="email">Email:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" required><br>
    <label for="dob">Date of birth:</label>
    <input type="date" id="bod" required>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to loop through each input every time an input changes:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var shouldShowSubmitBtn = true;

        $("input").change(function () {
            $(":input").each(function () {
                if ($(this).val() == '') {
                    shouldShowSubmitBtn = false;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

The code I used :

```
for (const input of inputs) {
            input.addEventListener(`input`, () => {
                for (const input of inputs) {

                        if (input.value.length === 0) {
                            submitButton.disabled = true;
                            cta.classList.add('is-disabled');
                            break;
                        } else {
                            submitButton.disabled = false;
                            cta.classList.remove('is-disabled');
                        }
                    }
            });
        }
```